# custom spring boot loader

Tags: spring-boot, classloader

I want to custom spring boot loader.
but now I have some questions:

1. how to compile spring boot ？
   I run "mvn clean install" in my spring boot project,but it blocked in flalow:
   [INFO] Running post-build script: xxx/spring-boot/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-loader/target/it/executable-props/verify.groovy

2.how effect my new code

3.how custom LaunchedURLClassLoader.java and let it effect

Comment: Show some code please. Also, could you explain 2 and 3 please?

Comment: I can not compile spring boot project
and i want override LaunchedURLClassLoader.
no new code

Comment: I want to override LaunchedURLClassLoader to achieve encrypt and decrypt class file